# I was wondering why in C++ they say to use constant int instead of int when declaring an array size? What difference does it actually make in general?

Tags: c++

EX:

```
const int SIZE = 10; 
int arr[SIZE];
```

vs

```
int SIZE = 10; 
int arr[SIZE];
```

Even though the compiler doesn't seem to show any errors in the run time.

Comment: In c++ array size must be constant expressions. Your second example is non standard c++ and should be avoided.

Comment: When compiling use `-pedantic-errors`.  Then you will get an error for the second code block.

Comment: Visual Studio will show you an error if you try to compile the second version. gcc and clang unfortunately allow that by default.

Comment: "The compiler" is wrong if it accepts that second code example without issuing a diagnostic. That is not valid C++.